# how to add ( ) brackets to characters after the first word in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to put all the characters within brackets ( ) after the first word in a file,
for example:

```
g.setproperties "Title" "" "Comments" "" "UnitForce" "kN" "UnitLength" "m" "UnitTime" "s"  
g.bh 0 0
```

to

```
g.setproperties ("Title" "" "Comments" "" "UnitForce" "kN" "UnitLength" "m" "UnitTime" "s")  
g.bh (0 0)
```

Is there a quick way to do it in Notepad++ ? All the lines will start with `g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
^(\S+\s*)(.*)
```

Replacement string:

```
$1\($2\)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uJ6wO5/2)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this pattern:

```
^(g\.\w+\s+)(.+)
```

With this replacement string:

```
$1\($2\)
```

The regex should be straightforward, but the replacement pattern requires escaping the parentheses because of the [boost replacement string format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html).